# TYPO3 7.6. change typoscript hierarchy via extension-template

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-extensions

Is there a possibility to change the typoscript template hierarchy via an extension-template? Currently i have defined everything including all typoscript in my extension. This works fine with real_url configuration etc. But everything regarding indexed_search is overwritten by the original extension itself.

Is there a possibility to define the loading/parsing order of extensions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a dependency to all extensions that should load before your extension.
If you do not have a hard dependency, then make sure to list the extension as suggested, because this will make that it is loaded before your extension too.

Comment: In my `ext_emconf.php` i've listed indexed_search as dependency, but this does not works. I've also tried to add it as suggested, but this changed nothing.

Comment: You need to reinstall the extension in order to regenerate the PackageStates.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Open the TypoScript record, switch to the tab "Includes", at the bottom you will find the field **Static Template Files from TYPO3 Extensions:**. Select the value `Include before all static templates if root flag is set`.

Question is a duplicate of [Manage hierarchy / enforce priority of TS-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612743/manage-hierarchy-enforce-priority-of-ts-templates)