# Manage hierarchy / enforce priority of TS-templates

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

Well, there is actually another [guy with exact the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34081857/typo3-7-6-change-typoscript-hierarchy-via-extension-template). But until today, they didn't come up with a solution, that's why I'm asking it once again.

My entire TS is included by an extension in `TYPO3 7.6.8`. This works fine except with `indexed_search`. The TS inside my resources EXT get overwritten by the indexed_search default TS.

This is the order of the TS inside the Template-Analyzer:

1. SYS: TYPO3_CONF_VARS:FE:defaultTypoScript
2. EXT:fluid_styled_content/Configuration/TypoScript/...

... a bunch of other third party extensions ...

6. EXT:indexed_search/Configuration/TypoScript
7. EXT:templates_ext/Resources/Private/TypoScript
8. extbase
9. fluid
10. extensionmanager
11. belog
12. beuser
13. felogin
14. indexed_search
15. sys_note
16. realurl

So #7 is the extension which includes all my TS but it gets overwritten by #14. The only way to configure the `indexed_search` is inside the setup of the page template (which comes after all those above). But I want to avoid that to keep things clean.

**Is there a way to prioritize a certain TS so that it doesn't get overwritten?**

Answer (score 1):

Open the TypoScript record, switch to the tab "Includes", at the bottom you will find the field **Static Template Files from TYPO3 Extensions:**. Select the value `Include before all static templates if root flag is set`.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the TS from your template extension inside the root page Setup field like this (adjust the path if necessary, your example says Resources/Private/TypoScript?):

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:templates_ext/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.ts">
```

This should make sure that it is included AFTER all the other includes (I assume you included those via the includes tab?)